# Instagram API iOS client possible to logout of Instagram

Tags: ios, instagram, url-scheme

I have an app where user logs into Instagram through implicit auth with Oauth 2. Is there any way for user to log out or to relogin as different user?

As it is now, when I call the auth URL after user logs in, Safari browser is launched, then goes back to the app without displaying login fields. I need Safari to display login fields and allow user to enter uname and pass before control is passed back to app.

Answer (score 13):

> You can delete cookies of instagram by following way

```
       let cookieJar : NSHTTPCookieStorage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
    for cookie in cookieJar.cookies! as [NSHTTPCookie]{
        NSLog("cookie.domain = %@", cookie.domain)

        if cookie.domain == "www.instagram.com" ||
            cookie.domain == "api.instagram.com"{

            cookieJar.deleteCookie(cookie)
        }
    }
```

Comment: @thibautnoah Welcome..!!

Comment: This is not working for me

Answer (score 2):

call the instagram logout url (https://instagram.com/accounts/logout) and then call auth URL.

You can implement a logout button, so when the user click logout, it should call the logout url and then wait for a delay, show the button to login, then it will ask user to login.

Comment: and do i need to reference the client ID or url scheme?

Comment: The problem of this approach is that the app open a browser view and it wait for user interaction

Answer (score 1):

Please delete your cookies , thats it.Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.2

```
let cookieJar : HTTPCookieStorage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
        for cookie in cookieJar.cookies! as [HTTPCookie]{
            print("cookie.domain = %@", cookie.domain)

            if cookie.domain == "www.instagram.com" ||
                cookie.domain == "api.instagram.com"{

                cookieJar.deleteCookie(cookie)
            }
        }
```